# How to move Apps to SD on the LG P-705 with Android 4.0?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, app2sd

I can move apps manually or progammatically on my Samsung Galaxy Ace 1, but on my LG P-705 with newer android version there is no such an option. Apps like App2SD don't work as well.

Why does LG P-705 Android 4.0 Smartphone not have a move to SD feature?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should root your smartphone. Then, use Link2SDapp. Then, move the app to the SD card.

Comment: If possible, please provide a link to the app. :)

Answer (score 0):

first of all, you should root your phone, follow this link to find out how you can root your phone : [ONE CLICK ROOT YOUR LG LG-P705](https://www.oneclickroot.com/root/lge-lg-p705-iml74k-4-0-3/)
then you can use this apps to move your apps too your SD card :
[APP2SD 3](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.a0soft.gphone.app2sd&hl=en) or 
[AppMgr Pro III](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.a0soft.gphone.app2sd.pro&hl=en)